# Spring AOP. @Aspect annotation doesn't work with @Profile

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop, spring-profiles

I have this aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Profile("measure")
public class MyAspect {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(Measured)")
    private pointcutMethod() { }

    @Around
    public advice() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to be able to disable/enable it using profiles.
So when I don't specify "measure" profile, it doesn't work.

Comment: Please read: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) - a simple rewording should suffice to remove the "anyone implemented this" part, which would warrant a close as off topic.